# About Error: libcublasLt.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning, cublas

my system is ubuntu20.04 ，conda env python==3.8, CUDA==11.8 ,cuDNN already installed, pytorch==2.0.0 pytorch-lightning==2.0.0 when i use pytorch-lightning to train my model , it raised en error: Could not load library libcublasLt.so.12. Error: libcublasLt.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Aborted (core dumped)

i try `sudo apt-get install libcublas-12-0` but `E: Unable to locate package libcublas-12-0`